# Xamarin - Cannot use PopModalAsync

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

I am trying to use `PopModalAsync` to remove the modal page. However, the `Navigation.ModalStack.Count` is 0. If I use `PopModalAsync`, it will throw an exception:

`System.ArgumentOutOfRangeException: Index was out of range. Must be non-negative and less than the size of the collection. 
Parameter name: index`

I am using `Xamarin.Forms`. Here is some sample code:

App.cs (Potable)

```
public class App : Application
{
    public App()
    {
        // The root page of your application
        MainPage = new View.LoginPage();
    }
}
```

LoginPage.xaml.cs (Potable)

```
public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
{
    public INavigation _Navigate;
    public LoginPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        _Navigate = Navigation;
    }

    async void LoginBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
    {
        await _Navigate.PushModalAsync(new AuthenicationBrowser());
        //await _Navigate.PopModalAsync(); it is work at here
        Debug.WriteLine("Navigation.NavigationStack  LoginBtnClicked ===> {0}", Navigation.NavigationStack.Count); //getting 0
         Debug.WriteLine("Navigation.ModalStack  LoginBtnClicked ===> {0}", Navigation.ModalStack.Count);  // getting 1    
    }

    public async void PopModal()
    {
        Debug.WriteLine(Navigation.NavigationStack.Count);
        await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }



}
```

AuthenicationBrowser.cs (Potable) *** Edited: Put PopModalAsync ***

```
public partial class AuthenicationBrowser : ContentPage
{
    public AuthenicationBrowser()
    {
      InitializeComponent();
    }
    public async void PopModal()
    {
       Debug.WriteLine("Navigation.ModalStack  AuthenicationBrowser .PopModal===> {0}", Navigation.ModalStack.Count);  // getting 0    
       await Navigation.PopModalAsync();
    }
}
```

BrowserView.cs (Potable)

```
public class BrowserView : WebView
{
    public BrowserView()
    {

    }
}
```

AuthenicationBrowserRenderer.cs (Droid) *** Edited: Calling PopModal ***

```
  [assembly: ExportRenderer(typeof(BrowserView), typeof(AuthenicationBrowserRenderer))] 
 namespace App.Droid
 {
     class AuthenicationBrowserRenderer : WebViewRenderer
     {
       ... // Doing some Auth in OnElementChanged and using JavaScriptCallBack class after received json in Webview
     }
     public class JavaScriptCallBack: Java.Lang.Object, IValueCallback
     {
        public JavaScriptCallBack()
        {

        }
        public async void OnReceiveValue(Java.Lang.Object result)
        {
            Java.Lang.String json = (Java.Lang.String)result;
            string raw_json = json.ToString();
            Debug.WriteLine("raw_json  ====>>> {0}", raw_json);
            var login_page = new LoginPage();
            var auth_page = new AuthenicationBrowser();

            Debug.WriteLine(login_page.Navigation.ModalStack.Count); // getting 0
            Debug.WriteLine(auth_page.Navigation.ModalStack.Count); // getting 0
            auth_page.PopModal(); // Trying to do PopModalAsync 


         }
     }
 }
```

Comment: Wrap the LoginPage in a NavigationPage

Comment: i tried with `MainPage = new NavigationPage(new View.LoginPage());` ,but still cause same result. And I do not want to add it in `NavigationPage`

Comment: You want to pop the Authenticated browser right? You need to replace the pop in there.

Comment: Sorry, I cannot get your meaning. My purpose is that I want to push the modal page `AuthenicationBrowser` and dismiss the modal page `AuthenicationBrowser ` after getting result fro server.

Comment: Yep thats what I mean. You have to do: Navigation.Pop in the AuthenticationBrowser. Not in the LoginPage. Because you want the AuthenticationBrowser dismissed, so place it there.

Comment: I have edited, but still cause same result. Where the coding is wrong?

Comment: It looks like you're trying to pop too many times.
Can you put a break point before calling PopModalAsync() and try to find this count.

Navigation.NavigationStack.Count

Comment: @GvSharma It is 0

Comment: @GvSharma @Mittchel can do the trick with `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync()`. Is that the best way for my solution?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Finally, I may get the answer that  `App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();` can do the trick. The reason is that the `new LoginPage()` is called as a new `Content Page` not existing page.

If I call it from the `App.Current.MainPage` (The existing LoginPage), it can get the existing modal from Modal Stack.

So the solution can be  :

```
    public partial class LoginPage : ContentPage
    {

        public LoginPage()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

        }


        async void LoginBtnClicked(object sender, EventArgs args)
        {
            await Navigation.PushModalAsync(new AuthenicationBrowser());
        }

        public async void PopModal()
        {

            Debug.WriteLine("Navigation.ModalStack  PopModal ===> {0}", App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.ModalStack.Count);
            await App.Current.MainPage.Navigation.PopModalAsync();

        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

As it seems you had the wrong `Navigation` object. In my case I also had this wrong.

I displayed a modal page, which had it's own navigation bar (or Navigation object). So when I wanted to dismiss this modal page I got the mentioned exception, because there were no other pages on the navigation stack. It was the wrong object ...

Answer (score 0):

For me I was calling PushModalAsync when I should have been calling PushAsync there was no items to push for PushModelAsync